# Design a View like a google Info Window in shape

Tags: android, google-maps, view, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I really don't like to use Info windows to show custom information. I am fed up with their default features. So, I want to Show a View instead of the infowindow, when a marker is clicked. I want the border shape of the View to be like the Infowindow.

I am in need to show some animated stuff, so and so. 
 Please suggest me the solution. Please suggest me if I can go this way. 
 And please suggest your Ideas and share useful links.

Any help is appreciated!!
 Thanks for your valuable help!!

Comment: @MaciejGorski, I tried by adding google infowindow to a marker. I have inflated a layout xml to that infowindow. But if I click on the particular ImageView(in the layout added to infowindow), the whole infowindow is getting selected!! If this is teh case, how could I add buttons and force user to click on those buttons in infowindow? and also Tried with Alert dialog. Same case with alert dialog also. I am fed up with these issues!!  Any ideas regarding this are welcome!!

Comment: Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the MarkerDemoActivity in Google Maps API v2 samples. It contains code for customizing info windows and animating markers. 
To get the samples, go to your Android SDK folder and follow this path:

```
sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps
```

I don't know if this will be sufficient for your needs, but I hope it will at least help you!